# Design Patterns for enriching Feathers services with relational records

Tags: typescript, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize, feathers-hook

I am trying to create a simple app, with a data one-to-many relationship. Where a site contains many locations. I am using feathers js and sequelize (with sqlite). The standard `GET` functionality in feathers will return a site or a list of sites. However, I can't see how you are "supposed too" return child records.

If I was doing this in sequelize directly, I would do something like:

```
    db.Site.findAll({
        include: [db.Location]
    }).then(function (sites) {
        res.status(200).json({
            data: sites
        });
    }).catch(err => res.status(500).send({ error: err }));
```

From the feathers guides, it looks as though I could put this logic in a hook (after the standard query?), and replace the collected data with the result of this query (and double the number of db calls). Or I could query just for locations with the current `siteId` as their `parentId` (again douubling the number of database calls).

However, I wondered whether there was a neater way built into feathers, to ensure that every time the standard `GET` call is made, it's child elements are included.

Answer (score 0):

This is done via `params.sequelize` and documented in more detail in [this FAQ](https://docs.feathersjs.com/help/faq.html#sequelize-models-and-associations) and the [feathers-sequelize documentation](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize#associations) which shows using a `before` hook on the server like this:

```
// GET /my-service?name=John&include=1
function (context) {
  const { include, ...query };

   if (include) {
      const AssociatedModel = context.app.service('fooservice').Model;
      context.params.sequelize = {
         include: [{ model: AssociatedModel }]
      };
      // Update the query to not include `include`
      context.params.query = query;
   }

   return context;
}
```